# LPTHW Exercise 20

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a few questions on the online book Learn Python The Hard Way Exercise 20.

First of all when I only type:

```
from sys import argv

script, input_file = argv

def print_all(f):
    print f.read()
```

There is no text in the output. I did:

```
$ python ex20.py text.txt
```

in terminal so there is no error.

Comment: [Don't use LPTHW](http://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints)

Comment: Why? Please tell me your experience with it and are you using any better source for learning? Thanks!

Comment: That is a link to reasons not to use it. The same site has a list of good tutorials.

Comment: You declare a function, but never call it.

Comment: So why even use it then?

Comment: `def print_all` and `def print_a_line` are function definitions. You have call or invoke the defined functions by passing required arguments. When you call the functions, the passed arguments are assigned to the function parameters.